# Encrypting key passphrase with user password - bad idea?

Tags: php, security, encryption, cryptography, passwords

I currently have a private key meant to be used for signing documents which is currently stored in a keystore. Despite the server being dedicated for this task (ie: no one has access to it other than the signing service running over https) I am unwilling to keep the password for the keystore in plain text. I recognize that this could be a potential risk if anyone ever had access to the server.

What I am thinking could be appropriate would be keeping the password for the Keystore encrypted in the server with the user's password. So, whenever the user wanted to make use of the private key it would be necessary to provide his password. Password changes would not be a problem since the encrypted password could be decrypted with the old one and encrypted with the new one.

For an attacker to gain access to the PK it would be necessary to guess someone's password and have access to the server to decrypt the password to access the KeyStore. Strong password policies could be enforced to avoid weak passwords and not all users would be given the possibility to sign documents.

I was reading the [OpenSSL PHP page](http://php.net/manual/en/book.openssl.php) when I found this comment (with a score of `-8`):

> After generating a key pair with OpenSSL, the public key can be stored
>   in plain text format. I then encrypted the private key itself using
>   regular mcrypt with the human-memorizable key of my choice and
>   converted it to ACSII using base64_encode. Then to get the private key
>   back, I just decrypted it with mcrypt. This way I could store the
>   encrypted private key on the server without worrying about having
>   things stored unencrypted.
>
> Of course, this will only be as good as your human-memorizable key is
>   and can potentially reduce the security of your script if you choose
>   something simple or don't use salts.

So, is this such a bad idea or could this be used in production?

Comment: Who is "the user" in this scenario?

Comment: Employees accessing the application via the corporate LAN.

Comment: And each user has their own private key or its the same one?

Comment: It's the same one. Let me add that no one will know the actual keystore passphrase ever. Users' passwords are used to decrypt the ciphered keystore passphrase on the server that's dedicated for that purpose.

Comment: I don't understand how you would encrypt this same private key with each user's password without first storing it in plaintext...if it was only one user the question would make more sense to me, I think.

Comment: Let's say I keep some `.txt` files alongside the private key. For example `bob.txt` and `alice.txt`. Both of them should be allowed to sign documents and therefore need access to the PK. The contents of `bob.txt` would be the result of `encrypt(bobs_password, actual_keystore_password)`. This would require me to know their password for the initial creation of the files but this is not a problem since I can generate an initial password for them. Whenever Bob desires to make use of the PK, he needs to provide a password to decrypt the contents of `bob.txt`, in other words, the keystore passphrase

Comment: Whenever Bob desires to change his password a request is sent to the server, indicating the old password and the new one. The server would decrypt the ciphered keystore and encrypt it with the new password. All this will be done under HTTPS.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on what we call bad idea. The whole idea of security is to make violations more expensive and difficult to occur. But there sometimes exists a tradeoff where you lose usability for an added security, or in this case, there is a higher chance that more of your users might begin forgetting passwords if they should use a different password for this case rather than the same user-account passwords.

You must think if every now and then user passwords are required to be changed, users might get confused and forgetful, and then give it up and start writing their passwords in a file on their desktop! Would that really help? I know small and large organizations that give users PGP certificates where its passphrase is the same as the user's account password. So in the end it is really your choice! If it is me, if it is not the top secret documents that I am dealing with, I would use the same password as the user account.